# Placing 4 html elements in every corner of a div

Tags: html, css

Hi there and thanks for your help.
I have a div (180px to 75px) in which I need to place 3 paragraphes and an image.
Now I need to place those elements in all of the divs corners.
It should look something like this -> (I'm not allowed to post pictures yet. I hope you'll understand it anyway.)

This is what the div should look like (every color is an element), but I can't seem to get the description to the right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn8Q6.png

But no matter how I play around with the "display: inline-block" or the "float" I can't get it to work.

I hope someon of you can give me the answer?

```
<div style="width:180px; height: 75px; background-color: green;" id="achievement">
    <div>
      <p style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px" id="title">Title Title Title</p>
      <p style="margin:0px; float:right;" id="exp">500 exp</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="padding-left: 10px;" id="img"width="50" height="50" src="image.png"/>
      <p style="float:right; margin: 0px;" id="desc">Bla Bla Bla this is a description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I use an extern css file of course. I just used the style tag to make it easier for you to understand.)

Comment: Could you upload the picture to http://www.imgur.com, and edit your post with the link? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `position:relative` on the parent container to establish a positioning context. Then use `position:absolute` on all the children to put them in the appropriate corners.

```css
#parent {
    position:relative;
    border:3px solid blue;
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    padding:0;
}
p {
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
}
p:nth-child(1) {
    border-color:green;
    top:0;
    left:0;    
}
p:nth-child(2) {
    border-color:red;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
    border-color:yellow;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
    border-color:pink;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <p>First</p>
    <p>Second</p>
    <p>Third</p>
    <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**Sample implementation here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/63EFJ/)</kbd>

Comment: It's also a hopelessly better implementation than depending on `text-align` so I sure hope you'll reconsider which one to implement  :X

Comment: I'll sure take a look at that.
That is AFTER I went to sleep :)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I agree completely with you. Mine was just sort of a quick-fix ;)

Comment: The main point is that this implementation is not in any way dependent on the contents of the sub-elements for positioning. The bottom elements are **always** in the corner, because your CSS **explicitly** placed them there. They cannot escape it.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Your JSFiddle looks great at first, but as soon as you write a bigger text in the fourth element. It will go over ther third element. :(

Comment: Add a max-width of 50% to the elements to force linebreaks at proper position :) since the parent is fixed size every solution will have its 'drawbacks' logically.

Comment: I'm trying to complete the entire positions (top center / bottom center / center left etc') => but don't have much success with position: absolute. anyone have an idea how can i position the text for all the options? (9 options total).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `text-align:right` That did the trick for me anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/Neaw7/

Comment: Thank you for the REALLY fast answer but sadly it doesn't seem to work like that :(

The Description is placed under the div even if I change the display and the float parameters.

http://i.imgur.com/DLwFAIi.png

Comment: I think that's just because your width is to small. Set it to something bigger.

Comment: Oh... Nevermind, seems like I made a mistake adapting your answer. Works now.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by making the parent tag as position relative and child div tags by positioning absolute.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent{
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
#child1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#child2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#child3{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#child4{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: skyblue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    <div id="child3">
        <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    <div id="child4">
        <p>hi</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boostrap5 you can achieve the goal using the class `position-relative` on the parent, and `position-absolute top-0 end-0` or similar on the child, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/position/#position-values .

If you are using boostrap4, you need to explicitely add `top:0; left:0;` or similar to the style of the element, since `top-0` is not a class designation in bootstrap4.

Comment: this said, the answer by @niels-keurentjes  is what really helped me fix the problem in boostrap4  