# Add elements on all the four sides of a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an element on all the 4 sides of the div.
I don't want to use **box-sizing** as I have to apply event listeners on the elements that I would place on all the 4 sides.

I am able to add it to the left and right but how can I add it on all the 4 sides? And this also is not an elegant way.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
}

#sideEl {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}

#sideEl2 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="sideEl">
  <div id="sideEl2">
</div>
```

[image]

I had referred [Placing 4 html elements in every corner of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054381/placing-4-html-elements-in-every-corner-of-a-div) . But not able to get an idea how to place them along side borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the two other `div`s and use :

- a class to identify (style in other words) a side, let's call it `side`, that'll be used by the `div`s that act as sides. This class holds mutual styles for the sides like the `background-color` and the `position`.
- two additional classes :

  - `side-h` which is used by the sides that are horizontal (top and bottom sides). It holds the `width` and `height` for these specific sides as they do share the same values. Also, these sides have `cursor: n-resize` rule for a vertical cursor.
  - `side-v` which is used by the sides that are vertical (right and left sides). It holds the `width` and `height` for these specific sides as they do share the same values. Also, these sides have `cursor: w-resize` rule for an horizontal cursor.
- the `#side-top` and `#side-left` hold the same values for `top` and `left` rules.
- the `#side-bottom` and `#side-right` hold the same values for `bottom` and `left` rules.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.box .side {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

.box .side.side-h {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  cursor: n-resize;
}

.box .side.side-v {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}

#side-top, #side-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#side-right, #side-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="side side-h" id="side-top"></div>
  <div class="side side-v" id="side-right"></div>
  <div class="side side-h" id="side-bottom"></div>
  <div class="side side-v" id="side-left"></div>
</div>
```

> the ordering of the elements inside `.box` **can** be changed without affecting the final result.

Comment: @Enthu when using pseudo-elements you can't attach events to them.

Comment: oh so in the above link it is doing something different is it , I mean it would be great if you explain a bit :) , thanks

Comment: @Enthu he triggers the drag only if the user clicks on the border (see the calculation made in his code).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198439/discussion-between-enthu-and-ths).

Answer (score 3):

I swapped the `height` and `width` parameters for horizontally aligned elements so they are showed as intended. Also you should only be using one of those option ( `top` `right` `bottom` `left` ) to align element to one of four sides. Here's the code:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
}

#sideEl {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}

#sideE2 {
  background-color: brown;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
#sideE3 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
#sideE4 {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="sideEl"></div>
  <div id="sideE2"></div>
  <div id="sideE3"></div>
  <div id="sideE4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer was also correct , but dont know why the left and right elements were slightly displaced from the top and pushed down a bit in my html ,might be due to some other styles in my html code

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
}

#sideTop {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  cursor: w-resize;
}

#sideRight {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}

#sideBottom {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  cursor: w-resize;
}

#sideLeft {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="sideTop"></div>
  <div id="sideBottom"></div>
  <div id="sideRight"></div>
  <div id="sideLeft"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you may get the idea...

```css
.main-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.child {
  float: left;
}
.child:nth-child(odd) {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.child:nth-child(even) {
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: red;
}
.child:nth-child(4) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```